# Error while make visual studio code extension Cannot find package 'mem-fs' imported

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I am developing extensions for visual studio code. This extension is used for my daily work to track html code and find the duplication. So first, I install template generator with

```
npm install -g yo generator-code
```

then after I run:

```
yo code
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'mem-fs' imported from C:\Users\####\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\yeoman-enviroment\dist\environment-base.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:887:9)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:936:20)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1129:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:835:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36)
```

[image]